# Database creation error:encoding "UTF8" Odoo

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, odoo, odoo-16

I tried to create Odoo database on Ubunto and a got this error

Database creation error:encoding "UTF8" does not match
locale "en_Us" DETAIL:The chosen LC_CTYPE setting
requires encoding "LATIN1".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDHsY.png)

(Odoo 16 , Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Posgresql)

i have try to set local and fix in many to tutorial but cannot fix it

Comment: You need to change your database's `template1` database as described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Actually per [Template Databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) you just need to `CREATE DATABASE` explicitly using the `template0` database instead of the default `template1` database. As stated at link: *Another common reason for copying template0 instead of template1 is that new encoding and locale settings can be specified when copying template0, whereas a copy of template1 must use the same settings it does. This is because template1 might contain encoding-specific or locale-specific data, while template0 is known not to.*

Comment: You can check this link https://gist.github.com/joshteng/9895494

Comment: @WaleedMohsen, why mess with the `template1` database when there is the `template0` database that allows you specify any encoding/locale at will?